# Unreal Engine 4.26 keeps crashing on launch (Assertion Failed)

Tags: unreal-engine4

Whenever I open UnrealEngine 4.26 it crashes on launch and gives this error message:

> LoginId:78c520684d428eb9acaf65ac7d21e637
> EpicAccountId:8d775856d6dc40378581d9051e93af48
>
> Assertion failed: FInternationalization::Get().IsInitialized() == true
> [File:D:/Build/++UE4/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Internationalization/TextFormatter.cpp]
> [Line: 1018] FInternationalization is not initialized. An FText
> formatting method was likely used in static object initialization -
> this is not supported.
>
> UE4Editor_Core UE4Editor_Core UE4Editor_Core UE4Editor_Core
> UE4Editor_Core UE4Editor_Projects UE4Editor_Projects
> UE4Editor_Projects UE4Editor_Projects UE4Editor_Projects
> UE4Editor_Projects UE4Editor_Projects UE4Editor_Projects
> UE4Editor_Projects UE4Editor_CoreUObject UE4Editor_CoreUObject
> UE4Editor_CoreUObject UE4Editor_CoreUObject UE4Editor_Core
> UE4Editor_Core UE4Editor UE4Editor UE4Editor UE4Editor UE4Editor
> kernel32

After some researches on google, some people fixed similar problems by deleting the DerivedDataCache folder from the AppData, but it didn't work for me.

Reinstalling UE with my 8mb/s internet speed will be pain in the back, so tell me your thoughts below!

Thanks in advance!

[A screenshot of the error's window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkVOh.png)

Comment: probably some file got corrupted ... can we check integrity of downloaded files in epic client ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the file integrity in the epic games launcher by clicking the dropdown arrow on your engine version and clicking verify